# How to add data from Theme > Customize to WPGraphQL Schema?

Tags: wordpress, graphql, wp-graphql

I'm using Wordpress with WPGraphQL. In the theme customizer, I added some inputs through the `$wp_customize->add_control` function from Wordpress.

How can I add those to the WPGraphQL Schema so I can query them?

Comment: use `register_graphql_field` to extend schema, use `get_theme_mod` in resolver

Answer (score 0):

WPGraphQL have the function `register_graphql_field`, that you can use with this structure.

In the resolve function, just return the `get_theme_mod` with the id of your theme mod. Something like this:

```
add_action( 'graphql_register_types', function() {
  $field_config = [
    'type' => 'String',
    'resolve' => function( $source, $args, $context, $info ) {
      return get_theme_mod('my_theme_mod');
    },
  ];

  register_graphql_field( 'RootQuery', 'my_theme_mod', $field_config);
});
```

The `add_action` is for this executing only when using graphql.

More info in their documentation webpage: https://www.wpgraphql.com/2020/03/11/registering-graphql-fields-with-arguments/

Thanks to @xadm for the hints.